# Difference in copying files recursively from a drive using rsync

Tags: hard-drive, files, backup, rsync

I've used the command below to copy files from Windows drive to an external HDD, using the command:

```
rsync -azv --progress --exclude "/Windows" --exclude "/Program Files" --exclude "Program Files (x86)" ./* /media/ubuntu/external_hdd/c_drive
```

What's a good way to verify that all files were copied and their sizes are correct, etc? When I'm looking at the output folder on my external HDD `c_drive` properties, it tells me it has 60,712 items (215,4GB), but looking at the rsync command it, it tells me it copied 61029 files. Here's the end report from rsync:

> `sent 201,309,277,955 bytes received 1,039,371 bytes 20,370,383.74
>   bytes/sec total size 216,054,087,051 speedup is 1.07`

Calculation tells me this:
201,309,277,955 bytes - 187.483875039034 gigabytes
216,054,087,051 bytes - 201.216048608534 gigabytes.

So here's what it looks like:
rsync input has 61029 files, output folder has 60712 files
rsync shows it copied 187GB (or 201GB?), output folder has 215,4GB

So I've got less files, but the folder size has grown some 15-20GB?

-edit- I tried using `diff` command to compare both folders.

```
diff --exclude="Program Files" --exclude="Program Files (x86)" --exclude="Windows" -r /media/ubuntu/OS media/ubuntu/external_hdd/c_drive
```

And it gave me a few files that have been made afterwards - hidden files starting with a dot (.hiberfil.sys.[idnumber] and .pagefile.sys.[idnumber]), but this gave me 9,4GB of indifference, but there's still the remaining 6GB (or 11?).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `diff` tool seems to be a reasonable thing to determine differences between directories, as you noted. That's what I'd be doing.

```
diff -r source_directory destination_directory
```